# Xam.Plugin.Media 'Too many open files'

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin forms PCL app, using the Xam.Plugin.Media helper.  I have a page where the user invokes a camera helper on a button push to take a picture. The bytes from the camera helper return to the page and serve as the source for an image.  There is a save button on the page where I basically call the messaging service and save the bytes to PCL SQlite storage.  The problem is I get about 3 successful loads of this page, and can take a picture with the camera helper before I get an exception AFTER the image is taken with the camera, but before it returns with the bytes.  The exception message is 'Too many open files'.  This is for iOS.  All relevant code is below.  Thanks

Camera Helper:

```
 public class CameraHelper
{
    private MediaFile file;

    public async Task<byte[]> TakePicture()
    {
        await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

        if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
        {
            throw new Exception("No camera available");
        }

       using (MediaFile file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
        {
            Name = $"photo{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")}.jpg",
            PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Small,
            CompressionQuality = 80,
            AllowCropping = true,
        }))

        {
            if (file == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            using (System.IO.Stream stream = file.GetStream())
            {
                ImgBytes = new byte[stream.Length];
                await stream.ReadAsync(ImgBytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(stream.Length));
                file.Dispose();
            }
        }
        return ImgBytes;
    }
}
```

Take Photo Page:

```
 <ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="12,10,12,15">

        <Label x:Name="photoTypeLabel" Text="Take *photo type* Photo" VerticalOptions="Start" />

        <StackLayout Padding="0,30,0,70">

            <ffimageloading:CachedImage x:Name="Image" Grid.Row="0" FadeAnimationEnabled="true"  Aspect="AspectFill"
                                         HeightRequest="200" WidthRequest="125" >
                <ffimageloading:CachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnImageTapped" />
                </ffimageloading:CachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
            </ffimageloading:CachedImage>
        </StackLayout>

        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
               Text="{ x:Static local:GrialShapesFont.PhotoCamera }"
                Style="{StaticResource FontIcon}"
                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                Opacity="1"
                FontSize="60"
                TextColor="#FF000000"
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                HorizontalOptions="Center">
            <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnCameraTapped" />
            </Label.GestureRecognizers>
        </Label>

        <Button Style="{StaticResource PrimaryActionButtonStyle}" VerticalOptions="End" Text="Save" WidthRequest="{ artina:OnOrientationDouble
                    LandscapePhone=200,
                    LandscapeTablet=400 }" HorizontalOptions="{ artina:OnOrientationLayoutOptions
                    PortraitPhone=Fill,
                    LandscapePhone=Center,
                    PortraitTablet=Fill,
                    LandscapeTablet=Center }" Clicked="saveButtonClicked" />

        <Button  Style="{StaticResource PrimaryActionButtonStyle}" VerticalOptions="End" Text="Cancel" WidthRequest="{ artina:OnOrientationDouble
                    LandscapePhone=200,
                    LandscapeTablet=400 }" HorizontalOptions="{ artina:OnOrientationLayoutOptions
                    PortraitPhone=Fill,
                    LandscapePhone=Center,
                    PortraitTablet=Fill,
                    LandscapeTablet=Center }"  Clicked="cancelButtonClicked" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Take Photo Page Code Behind:

```
  private async void OnCameraTapped(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        CameraHelper cameraHelper = new CameraHelper();

        try
        {
            ImgBytes = await cameraHelper.TakePicture();
            Image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
            {
                return new MemoryStream(ImgBytes);
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex.Message == "No camera available")
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Error", "No camera available", "Ok");
            }
            else
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Error", "Unable to take picture.", "Ok");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: updated camera helper to reflect first proposed answer

Answer (score 2):

If I'm reading [the code](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/blob/9d11e00f0c8745956d6cdc6013e3266e515bda57/src/Media.Plugin.Android/MediaPickerActivity.cs#L293) correctly, `GetStream` opens a new stream to the file every time. I would try wrapping your `CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync` call and the stream in `using` statements just to make sure they get disposed of properly.

```
public class CameraHelper
{
    public async Task<byte[]> TakePicture()
    {
        await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

        if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
        {
            throw new Exception("No camera available");
        }

        using ( MediaFile file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
        {
            Name = $"photo{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")}.jpg",
            PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Small,
            CompressionQuality = 80,
            AllowCropping = true,

        }) ) {

            if (file == null) {
                return null;
            }
            using (System.IO.Stream stream = file.GetStream()) {
                byte[] ImgBytes;
                ImgBytes = new byte[stream.Length];
                stream.Read(ImgBytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(stream.Length));
            }
        }
        return ImgBytes;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that looked promising but I still get the same error

Comment: I did check for that, this is the only place.  Unless the ffimageloading type images load from files behind the scenes?  Otherwise I'm just using the byte array that comes from the camera helper and nothing else

Comment: @PatrickGoode do you see any native crash? Is it all managed stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

I sugest you to see Xamarin Essential camera view. You can implement your own custom camera screen.

https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/cameraview?source=recommendations

Then you can save the images in your local storage and just save the path in local database, or if you want can save in Base64 string, but i don't recomend.